# H2: Restore a (in-memory) database from a backup file

Tags: java, h2

H2 provides a [BACKUP](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#backup) command that can be used from a SQL statetement and creates a backup file:

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:nioMemFS:atestdb";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url); 
       Statement s = con.createStatement()) {
   s.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table ( test_values VARCHAR(255) )");
   s.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (test_values) VALUES ('abc'), "
     + "('def'), ('hji')");
   s.execute("BACKUP TO 'backup.zip'");  // writes to backup.zip
}
```

<s>This also works for in-memory databases</s> (**edit:** it works with the [nioMemFS](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system) file system but not with plain in-memory databases; see Oleg`s answer below). Is there also a command for restoring such a database file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BACKUP](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#backup) command shouldn't work for in-memory database, when I try I get [DATABASE_IS_NOT_PERSISTENT](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html#c90126) error, if the backup command works for you, you're probably not using a persistent database.

You can use the [SCRIPT](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) and [RUNSCRIPT](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#runscript) to backup and restore respectively via creating and running an sql script from the database.

```
SCRIPT TO 'backup.sql';
RUNSCRIPT FROM 'backup.sql';
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I updated the example in my question. It seems to work with the `nioMemFS` file system (at least it writes something to disk). Right, the `RUNSCRIPT` option works but I thought the backup function could be faster as it writes a binary format.